# How to use my drive without administartive permission

Tags: drive

I have my 1tb drive which have my flutter projects. My drive always asks for administrative permission. Whenever I save files it asks permission and also shows error showing denial of permission. Please help me remove this file from use of administrative or completely allow this  drive for administrative permission.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Do you have a separate administrator account, or is your account the only user account? Kindly [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1324588/edit) your question with these information.

Comment: Do you use this drive on other computers as well? Which file system does it have? Can you edit your question and include the output of `ls -la "/path/to/mount"` Where `/path/to/mount/` is something like `/media/username/harddrive`.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a solution(Do this in a terminal). It will change the permission of all the files in the drive to your user(So, be careful):

1. Go to the directory where you have mounted your hard disk.
2. Change the drive's permissions to belong to you. type this `sudo chown -R <your-username> .` and then enter your root(admin) password.

And you won't need root(administrative) permissions to change any part of the drive anymore.

Comment: Please be careful. This will recursively change all files and folders in the whole location. That might or might not be what OP intends. Without further information from OP, I would not recommend doing that.

Comment: Thanks it worked